# ASP MVC url/link generation on Area produces empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

I am using ASP MVC 5 and trying to generate a link in my view inside the "ControlPanel" Area

my view rootfolder/Areas/ControlPanel/Views/CourseCategory/Index.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
@Html.ActionLink("delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
```

my AreaRegistration

```
public class ControlPanelAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "ControlPanel";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

            context.MapRoute(
                name: "ControlPanel.CourseCategory",
                url: "controlpanel/course-categories/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CourseCategory", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Website.Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

RouteConfig file

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HomePage",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

        }
    }
```

my controller

```
namespace Website.Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers
{
    public class CourseCategoryController : ControlPanelController
    {

        public CourseCategoryController(IUnitOfWork uow)
            :base(uow)
        {
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_uow.Repository<CourseCategory>().GetAllOrderByCode());
        }
    }
}
```

now the output html produces empty href

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="">edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="">delete</a>
```

what is the correct way of generating link on Html.ActionLink or Url.Action and Url.RouteUrl in this case?

Comment: try specifying the area,  in the new section add area = "" whatever you area is

Comment: already tried that, based on Tommy's solution. check my comment

Comment: @Daskul - updated my answer based on some additional info I see in your question.  Let me know if that helps anything.

Comment: Hello, is it solved? I am also encountering the same problem. Thanks

Comment: check Tommy's answer on the Edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the controller in your route values (I noticed you are not specifying one anywhere in your `@Html.ActionLink`)

```
@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { controller="CourseCategory", id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
```

Or - an alternative overload of the `Html.ActionLink`

```
@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", "CourseCategory", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
```

Lastly, it never hurts to include the area name as part of the RouteValues dictionary, but this is not required.

**EDIT**

It looks like you updated your question with some additional information.  This does not look right (having a blank value for URL)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "HomePage",
  url: "",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

By default, it should look something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "HomePage",
  url: "{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

I would assume having a blank URL is definitely something that could cause a blank URL to be created in an `Html.ActionLink`.  These helpers looks at your route config to generate the URL and this one seems to be taking over probably everything since it matches everything.

Comment: tried those two but no luck. also adding area on routeValues didnt work @Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit",  new { controller = "CourseCategory", area = "ControlPanel", id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this area name along with id

```
@Html.ActionLink("edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id, area = "ControlPanel" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
@Html.ActionLink("delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id, area = "ControlPanel" }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the defaults which points to the Index action and action is not bound on the route!??